# Opportunity Validation

Tags: validation, opportunity

I'm trying to perform some validation on my opportunity page and I'm having difficulties. The following is the scenario..

If stage = close won (100%) or closed lost (0%) AND competitor = not known at this time, Validate that a new competitor value should be selected. (instead of current not known)

Here's the syntax I have so far that isn't working..
AND( OR( ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Award Close 100%"), ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost 0%"),
INCLUDES(Competitors_c, "Not Known At This Time") ) )

I'm new to Salesforce validation and I've been taking stabs at this all day and no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the OR close paren in the wrong spot try:

> AND(OR( ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Award Close 100%"), ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost 0%")), INCLUDES(Competitors_c, "Not Known At This Time") )

If those are the only 2 closed values then you could go with:

> AND(IsClosed, INCLUDES(Competitors_c, "Not Known At This Time"))